# ruby multithread problems related mutex array

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mutex

Recently I have to solve a problem related multithread in ruby.

I want to know if there is a Hash array of mutex that I can new a mutex when I want.

For example I have 3 resources and 5 threads. And two of my threads use the first resource , another two of them use the second resource and the last one use the third resource.

So the first two thread and the second two thread can only choose one of them to run, and the other have to wait. But the fifth thread can run with them.

So I hope there is a way to write mutex in an array.

Just like:

```
a = Hash.new
a["1"] = Mutex.new

def init    
  if a[string] == nil
    a[string] = Mutex.new
  end
end
```

thread runs :

```
thread1 do |string|
  a[string].synchronize do
    run_unsafe_code
  end
end
```

I write the code as I think below:

But It doesn't work:

I hope to see the result :

if 0 or 1 start,I will not see 0 or 1 start again until 1 or 1 is end.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'thread'
class Install
  @@x = Hash.new
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
    if @@x[url] == nil
      puts url
      @@x[url.to_sym] = Mutex.new
    end
  end

  def work()
    puts @url+" start."
    @@x[@url.to_sym].synchronize do
      5.times do 
        puts @url+" ."
        sleep 1
      end
    end
    puts @url+" end."
  end
end

thread = [] 
job = []

3.times do |i|
  job << Install.new(i.to_s)
end
2.times do |i|
  job << Install.new(i.to_s)
end       

job.each do |x|
  thread << Thread.new do
    x.work
  end
end

thread.each do |s|
  s.join
end
```

Hope someone can give me some help!! Much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. The way it works now it first prints "start" then waits for the mutex. Maybe you just want to print "start" after you actually got the lock to start:

```
def work()
  @@x[@url.to_sym].synchronize do
    puts @url+" start."
    5.times do 
      puts @url+" ."
      sleep 1
    end
    puts @url+" end."
  end
end
```